# scan barcode using android phone camera using ASP.net webpage?

Tags: javascript, android, asp.net

i am asp developer. i want to use android phone camera as scanner. How can i do that? the output need to goes in textbox on web page.
Is there is any API or Javascript for this?

Comment: i have done this in an android application to put barcode in edit text but dont know how to launch app from webpage and put result in webpage( web page is in asp.net)

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/